# How to calculate average of a sub-group

Tags: mean

There Is a problem i am unable to solve.

I have a population of 70 workers and I know that the average salary Is euro 281,21.
male workers are 30 and their average salary Is euro 300.
i should calculate how much Is the average salary of female workers.
Should I made a simplex proportion?
Thank you for any help

mark

Comment: This isn't a StackOverflow question. This is a mathematical question, and belongs on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) or [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

With the information you're given, a proportion is the only way to solve it.

```
Total salary - 70 X 281,21 = 19684,70
Men's salary - 30 X 300,00 = 9000,00
Women's salary - 19684,70 - 9000,00 = 10684,70
Women's average - 10684,70 / 40 = 267.1175
```